# Creating a variable array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have this piece of code from a program i am writing that doesn't work if i add a condition.
All the values are conveniently put based on those the original program would have.
I want to create an array of pointers:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {

        int *array2Ptr[3];
        int array2[3][5] = {{4,4,5,5,8},{2,8,2,3,6},{8,8,6,6,1}};
        
        for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i) {
             array2Ptr[i] = &array2[i][4];
        }
    
         for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i) {  
             printf("%d  ", *array2Ptr[i]);   
         }
      }
```

No problem here, it works fine.

Now, suppose i want `array2Ptr` to contain its element based on another array:

```
    int array1[3] = {3,0,3};
    int array2[3][5] = {{4,4,5,5,8},{2,8,2,3,6},{8,8,6,6,1}};
    int *array2Ptr[2];    //Has size 2 because it should only store 2 values

    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i) {

        if ( array1[i] != 0 ) {
           array2Ptr[i] = &array2[i][4];
        }
     }
    
     for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i) {  
         printf("%d  ", *array2Ptr[i]);   
    
     }
   }
```

This way i get a segmentation fault, why is that?

Comment: `array2Ptr` has size 2, but you are writing `array2Ptr[i]` for i=2 (3rd item). You need a separate counter for that array.

Comment: @EdmCoff yes I corrected it, in the original it would have been 2, but i get the error still.

Comment: Okay, then you are trying to print an undefined reference. `array2Ptr[1]` has not been set when you try to print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array2Ptr` has size 2, but you are writing `array2Ptr[i]` for i=2 (3rd item). Edit: In your updated/edited version, you are trying to print `array2Ptr[i]` when i=2, which was never set to anything (`array1[i] != 0` was false).

You need a separate counter for that array.

You could consider something like:

```
for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < 3 ; ++i) {
 if ( array1[i] != 0 ) {
  array2Ptr[j] = &array2[i][4];
  j++;
 }
}
```

That way, you only increment the iterator `j` for `array2Ptr` when it is used, but still use `i` as you currently are for the other arrays.

You might want to track that `j` outside the scope of the loop, so you know how many values to try printing.

Answer (score 0):

It's a better idea to use another iterator like `j` but if you want to do this with only one iterator, here's a simple solution for that particular code:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i) {

    if ( array1[i] != 0 ) {
        array2Ptr[i] = &array2[i][4];
    }
    else {
        array2Ptr[i] = &array2[i+1][4];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does this work in the general case? I agree it will work for this particular example, but if `array1` were `{3,0,0,0,3}` it seems odd to write values you don't want into `array2Ptr` (e.g. `array2Ptr[1]` will be set with a value that doesn't meet the `if` condition. And if `array1` ends in 0 (e.g. `{3,3,0}`) this will try to write `array2[3]` (i+1) which is out of range.

Comment: Yes it surely does not work for the general case, if `array1` is something like you write, then we would increment `i` inside the `else` part or open new conditions and it surely would not be useful. I just wrote it for this particular example, based on the specific values of these arrays.